# SQL index on join and group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a query that is running slowly.  I'm pretty sure that the bottleneck is a sequential scan in the plan, so I would like to build appropriate indexes and/or rearrange my query to improve upon that.

Here is my query (and [here is a fiddle with a schema and test data](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qu22JUByXD42dufSeY9k78/0)):

```
SELECT conversations.id, max(messages.timestamp) as latest_message FROM
    conversations JOIN messages on conversations.id = messages.cid
    GROUP BY conversations.id ORDER BY latest_message;
```

I have made indexes on all of the involved columns, and nested indexes on `cid` and `timestamp` in both directions, all to no avail.  The sequential scan remains:

```
 Sort  (cost=31.31..31.56 rows=100 width=12)
   Sort Key: (max(messages."timestamp"))
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=26.99..27.99 rows=100 width=12)
         Group Key: conversations.id
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=3.25..21.99 rows=1000 width=12)
               Hash Cond: (messages.cid = conversations.id)
               ->  Seq Scan on messages  (cost=0.00..16.00 rows=1000 width=12)
               ->  Hash  (cost=2.00..2.00 rows=100 width=4)
                     ->  Seq Scan on conversations  (cost=0.00..2.00 rows=100 width=4)
```

How can I improve this query and/or what indexes can I build to fix these sequential scans?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `join`:

```
SELECT m.cid, max(m.timestamp) as latest_message
FROM messages m 
GROUP BY m.cid
ORDER BY latest_message;
```

This should be able to use an index on `messages(cid, timestamp desc)`.  However, it might be faster to write this as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (m.cid) m.*
FROM messages m
ORDER BY m.cid, m.timestamp DESC;
```

With the same index.

Comment: The index will only help if the table has been vacuumed recently.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe . . . For the `group by` or for both queries?

Comment: For both, I'd say. Apart from an index-only scan, an index could not be used.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe . . . I would expect the index to be used for the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: PostgreSQL has no "index skip scan".